# MS pie chart with 2 querys

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, mschart, pie-chart

i have two queries which give two different values

One query gives the freespace

```
select sum(freesize) as freespace from freespace
```

the next query gives totalspace

```
select sum(NumRegions) as totalspace from fileidtofilename
```

then usedspace= totalspace- freespace

Now i want to display the usedspace region and freespace region in the piechart...

any suggestions

the piechart is:

```
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart4" runat="server" >
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you do it:

First i got the free space and used space using SQl query's

then i did this... hope this helps some1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        GetFreeSpace();
        GetTotalData();
        usedSpace = totalSpace - freeSpace;

        // Display 3D Pie Chart

        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

        Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Inside";

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;



        // Display a Title

        Chart1.Titles.Add("Show Space");



        // Add Data to Display

        string[] xValues = { "Used Space","Free Space" };

        double[] yValues = { usedSpace,freeSpace};

        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);



        // Call Out The Letter "Free Space"

        Chart1.Series[0].Points[1]["Exploded"] = "true";



        // Display a Legend

        Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("Alphabet"));

        Chart1.Legends["Alphabet"].Title = "Letters";

        Chart1.Series[0].Legend = "Alphabet";


    }
```